# save a new object using key from another object

Tags: python, django

When I create and save a new object with data submitted from a form and I want to use the id of the recently created object to create and save another object, is there any sort of guarantee that the id for the earlier object is the same used for the second object?

If not, is there a more guaranteed way to make sure this is the case?

In the example below, there is an FK relationship between `App1Name` and both of `App2Name` and `App3Name`

```
    obj1 = App1Name()
    obj1.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    form = App1NameForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()  # save App1Name obj1 into database
        obj2 = App2Name(notice=obj1)
        obj2.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        obj2.save()

        obj3 = App3Name(notice=obj1)
        obj3.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        obj3.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set `default` for `created_on` field

```py
class App1Name(models.Model):
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...
```

And then you can use it like this

```py
form = App1NameForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj1 = form.save()
    obj2 = App2Name(notice=obj1)
    obj2.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    obj2.save()

    obj3 = App3Name(notice=obj1)
    obj3.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    obj3.save()
```

`form.save()` returns model's instance and save record to the database unless you call it with parameter `commit=False`

I believe if `obj1` isn't stored in database calling `save` on `obj2` would throw exception.